# the i18n meaning in context

Tags: jakarta-ee, xhtml

In a code snippet I saw, I want to understand the use of the i18n(internationalization) in the code..can anyone just simply expalain to me why it is there.. I just want to undersand why there is the "i18n.createTitle" does this mean, it translate the language to english kind of internationalization or what? this might be a stupid question but i am a newbie..thanks..

```
<ui:composition template="/_decorator.xhtml">
    <ui:define name="title">#{i18n.createTitle}</ui:define>
    <ui:define name="heading">#{i18n.createHeading}</ui:define>
    <ui:define name="body">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In few words: you have a properties file for each language. In these files you have a label for each piece of text. for example:

i18n_ES.properties: (ES for Spanish)

```
helloworld=Hola Mundo
share_button=Comparte esta entrada
```

i18n_EN.properties: (EN for English)

```
helloworld=Hello World
share_button=Share this post
```

The browser request usually has language preferences in the header, so the response uses that to choose the text. If you want to support more languages, you need to create more properties files.

Then you can use a i18n to load the properties and request the text: i18n.helloworld, for example.